# CakePHP: Plugin can't extend AppController inside main src

Tags: php, cakephp, namespaces

I am using CakePHP 3. I have been looking for ways to make my application modular and it was suggested that I use plugins to do that. So I've decided to give that a shot. Please see my previous question: [Modular Directory Structure With CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581668/modular-directory-structure-with-cakephp). I have a plugin (module) called Client -  it has a controller called ClientsController.

When I visit it using 'http://localhost/client/clients/index' it doesn't work.I get a missing controller error. I found out it was because of extending App\Controller\AppController which lies in the main directory. I have everything common among the plugins inside the main src directory.

What's wrong?

Why can't I extend `App\Controller\AppController`?

### Error

[image]

### My Code

```
<?php

use App\Lib\OC\OCSSP;
use Cake\Network\Exception;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Utility\Text;


use App\Controller\AppController;

/**
 * Clients Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\ClientsTable $Clients
 */
class ClientsController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

    }

}
```

Comment: why do you have a namespace in the error code but not in what is posted above?  Perhaps you forgot that bit :) `namespace Client\Controller;`

Comment: Since the controller has not been found ( false positive).  CakePHP has suggested to me that the code in the error is what I use to create the controller.

Comment: Yes but you neglected to use the namespace, which means Cake is looking for `\Client\Controller\ClientsController` and you gave it jjust `\ClientsController`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: `I found out it was because of extending App\Controller\AppController` - This is a false conclusion. I would recommend you _bake_ the plugin and compare to your existing code, just moving files around won't work as if the file's in the right place with the wrong namespace it's like the class doesn't exist.

Comment: It was because I deleted the AppController for the plugin. I put it back and everything worked fine. It was already extending App\Controller as BaseController. So yes I was sort of wrong to conclude that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know cake, but from the look of it you simply forgot the namespace the error message suggest using.

```
namespace \Client\Controller
```

This will result in a scope resolution error, you see it's like naming the class

You have a class named

```
 \ClientsController
```

And cake is looking for one named this

```
\Client\Controller\ClientsController
```

Also note you want the namespace to be the first line of `code` in the file after the opening php tag.

```
<?php
 namespace ....
```